# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 10 Problem 10

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)$ = $x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$  for $x ≠ 0$ , and let $f(0)=0$. Suppose also that $h$ and $k$ are two functions such that
>
> $h'(x) = \sin^2(\sin(x + 1))$
>
> $k'(x) = f(x + 1)$
>
> $h(0) = 3$
>
> $k(0) = 0$
>
> Find
>
> (i) $ (f$ $\circ$ $h)'(0)$.
>
> (ii) $(k$ $\circ$ $f)'(0)$.
>
> (iii) $\alpha$'$(x^2)$, where $\alpha(x)$ = $h(x^2)$.

First I have $f'(x)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x≠0$ & $f'(0) = 0$ for $x=0$

(i) $\quad\begin{aligned}[t] (f\circ h)'(0)&=f'(h(0))h'(0)\\
&=f'(3)\sin^2\sin(1))\\
&=\biggl[6\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)-\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)\biggr]\sin^2(\sin1)\end{aligned}$

(ii) $(k$ $\circ$ $f)'(0)=0$

(iii) $\alpha'(x^2)$, where $\alpha(x)=h(x^2)$

$$\alpha(x^2)=h(x^4)\rightarrow\alpha'(x^2)=h'(x^4)4x^3=\sin^2(\sin(x^4+1)) = 4x^3.$$

I want to know if I made a mistake in (i) & (ii)

Comment: how did you get $f'(0)=0?$

Comment: @Arnaldo, as it is $f(0)= 0$, then $f'(0) = 0$

Comment: $f(0)=0$ doesn't necessarily imply $f'(0)=0$, I'm afraid. Take $f(x)=x$. $f(0)=0$, but $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: The conclusion $f'(0)=0$ is correct but you need to apply definition of derivative as a limit to reach that conclusion.